# How to determine Unix text files in C?

Tags: c, file, unix, text

I am writing a C program that looks at all files in the current directory using DIR, opendir(), and readdir(), then assigning them to a dirent struct as below.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DIR *d;
    char *dir_name = ".";
    struct stat s;

    d = opendir(dir_name);

    while (1) {
        struct dirent *entry;  

        entry = readdir(d);

        if (!entry) 
            break;

        //how to check if this is a text file before printing?
        printf ("%s\n", entry->d_name);
    }
    closedir(d)
}
```

What I need to find out is how to test the file to see if it is a text file.  I thought of using stat() to look at the mode.  I can exclude directories this way.  For binaries I thought I could look for executable bits, but that would be a problem for scripts, for instance, which are executable text files.

Any suggestions on how I might be able to programmaticaly filter for only text files?

Comment: What do you mean by a text file? One that only contains ascii? Or that contains written text encoded somehow?

Comment: You can only make guesses based on file extension or statistics on the file contents. All files are binary. "Text" is just an interpretation based on an encoding.

Comment: Are you allowed to invoke a command line tool? If so, just invoke `file` and then parse its output.

Comment: I thought about file, and that would be perfect if I could do it within the program.

Comment: @user2227422 you will need to read up on `fork` and `exec` to be able to invoke `file` from your code. I like the libmagic suggestion better however.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I gave up trying to make libmagic work, and just decided to use the following algo to loop through the contents of a file looking for directories and non ascii characters.  There is probably some kind flaw here, but it seems to work on the files I have tested it on.

```
is_text = 1;

while ((r = read(fs, &ch, sizeof(ch))) != 0) {
  if (r < 0) {
    is_text = 0;
    break;
  }
  if (ch < 0) {
    is_text = 0;
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

By using libmagic and looking into mime types

Comment: When I try to include magic.h, I get "fatal error: magic.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: To be explicit, this is the library used by `file` so this seems like a suitable answer. Note, though, that this approach is somewhat prone to false positives. While the developers take reasonable precautions to avoid misclassifications, many file formats are simply too poorly specified to be identified reliably. And human-generated free-form text files are always rich and varied.

Comment: On many platforms you will need to install a package `libmagic-dev` or similar to get the C headers etc.

Comment: @ParahatMelayev so my gcc command would look something like gcc -lmagic myprog.c -o myprog?

Comment: That's correct and of course you must have the library installed like @tripleee stated. Most of the modern *nix releases have it by default.

Comment: @tripleee Do you know a good place to download libmagic-dev?  I found a download here http://sourceforge.net/projects/libmagic/ but the magic.h doesn't have the magic_t struct, for instance.

Comment: Depending on your distro, simething like [`sudo aptitude install libmagic-dev`](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/libmagic-dev). The official sources are at http://www.darwinsys.com/file/ -- haven't examined Sourceforge, but I'd assume it's an abandoned fork.